# Filling an array in VBA conditionally

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

Lately I have been working on coding a Word macro in VBA to save time on certain documents. The idea is to fill the second column of a table with procedures based on a string of numbers from the first column. I have one function that reads the first column, which is working just fine. I pass the array containing that data to another function. I have verified that I am passing correctly. My problem comes about when I try to populate the array for the second column based on the array for the first column.I have an array of structures acting as a sort of "key;" each element of the "key" contains the string of numbers to compare the first column to as one member, and its corresponding procedure as another.This function looks similar to this:

```
Sub myFunction(ByRef codesFromTable() As String, ByRef procedures() As String)
  Dim key(3) As myType
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer
  key(0).code = "1234"
  key(0).procedure = "Procedure 1"
  key(1).code = "2345"
  key(1).procedure = "Procedure 2"
  key(2).code = "3456"
  key(2).procedure = "Procedure 3"
  For x = 0 To 5
    For y = 0 To 2
        If StrComp(codesFromTable(x), key(y).code = 0 Then
            procedures(x) = key(y).procedure
    Next y
  Next x
```

Every time I test this code on a table, the procedures array ends up completely being filled by the information from the last element in the key array. Any input would be valuable and appreciated.

Comment: Use Next x and Next y

Comment: @Whome Would this really make a difference? I was under the impression that the Next keyword is for incrementing the counter in the loop. Also, it seems as though the counter are incremented, and that the data from the final iteration is being assigned to all of the elements of the procedures array. Regardless, thank you for your input. I will test this tomorrow and follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two problems exist in your code:

(1) In the line "If StrComp(codesFromTable(x), key(y).code) Then"

"StrComp" returns 0 when two arguments are equal. Unfortunately, 0 means FALSE in VBA.
Your code set 'procedure' when the first column is NOT MATCHed to key.

That line should be corrected as follows.

```
If StrComp(codesFromTable(x), key(y).code) = 0 Then
```

(2) About contents of "codesFromTable(x)"

By the problem of (1), if first column is equal to key(0).code or key(1).code, procedure becomes key(2).procedure.

This does not explain why procedure becomes key(2).procedure when first column is equal to key(2).code.

I suspect that type of codesFromTable(x) is not String but Integer.

You can check the type of codesFromTable() by adding type to arguments as follows.

```
Sub myFunction(ByRef codesFromTable() as String, ByRef procedures() as String)
```

If type of codesFromTable(x) is Integer, type mismatch error occured while compiling.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Within the function that I pass codesFromTable() from, it is declared as a string. I pass it by reference to this function, which I assumed would preserve it as a string. I will try your suggestion.  Regarding your first suggestion, I had no idea that the StrComp function returns a 0 when the strings are equal. I assumed that it would return true. That explains a lot! I will try both suggestions tomorrow and follow up afterwards.

Comment: I think StrComp function in excel's VBA (    http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strcomp.php ) is sama to word's VBA. StrComp(str1,str2) returns 0 if str1=str2, returns 1 if str1>str2 and return -1 if str1<str2. This comparison ability is useful for using sorting etc.

Comment: After trying this and @Whome's suggestion, the script is still behaving the same way.

Comment: Had you try to step execution of your code on visual basic editor? Step wise execution is good tool to know how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

I feel very silly now. After looking at the contents of the arrays, I realized that the `StrComp` function was always returning 1 or -1 because the strings that were being input from the table had a delimiting character attached to the end. My code still would not have worked properly had @Fumu 7 not explained how `StrComp` worked, so I'll mark that as the answer.